# How to set IE as the default browser?

Tags: internet-explorer

Just a few days back I made Chrome my default browser. Can you please suggest how to make IE the default browser again?

Comment: But ... why IE? I mean, seriously!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **Tools** menu .. Then **Internet Options** then click on **Programs** tab .. *check this box* ---- **Tell me if Internet Explorer is not a default browser**

Answer (score 3):

In IE 8:

Tools > Internet Options > Programs.

There's a <kbd>Make Default</kbd> button at the top of the tab.

Comment: thanx for the answer .. its done ..

Answer (score 3):

[Here is one more alternative](http://www.winxptutor.com/iedefault.htm) for XP ..

Comment: Nice! Accepted answer didn't work for me (I'd already tried) - Chrome just wouldn't let go - but this worked a treat.